# div height not fully 100% at browser window in firefox but works great in chrome, ie & safari

Tags: html, css

I searched for hours for this very annoying issue on div 100% height of browser window.
Read about 15 articles on StackOverflow and other forums but none of them offered a solution. The grey bar at the left should be 100% vertical to browser window, not div content.

I tried min-height:100%, display:block, cell, table, table-cell, inline-block etc.
Just can't get it to work. And the most annoying part of it: it worked at the beginning.
Apparently I altered the code in time but saw the problem too late so I don't know what worked.

The classes that could be the problem are:

## maincontainer

.navigation
.content

Could someone please help by trying/correct the code?
I'm pulling my hair out here ;)

<strike>The page in question is https://www.paybrick.com/example.php</strike> Dead link

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to take out the empty div <div id="res"></div> or fill it with some value. Empty divs sometimes present problem in Firefox.

Comment: Thank's for your reply.
I tried it but it didn't worked. I tried with a value and without the res div. Any other thoughts? if I add a absolute amount of height pixels on #maincontainer it works, but the value has to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#maincontainer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%; /* try to give value in px instead of percent */
}
```

Comment: This worked!!
Thank you sooo much!

Thanks everyone for your time and quick responses.

Comment: Note that the `min-height` setting is pointless, as it has no effect when you use `display: table`.

Comment: `min-height` is effective for `display: table` when `height` is also provided. Try it in the above code! Use:
    height: 95%; min-height: 400px;

Answer (score 2):

It's the combination of `display: table` and `min-height: 100%` on the `#maincontainer` elements that doesn't work.

If you remove the `display: table` from it, the `min-height: 100%` works and the height is correct (but the layout inside it doesn't work as it uses the table).

If you use `height: 100%` instead of `min-height: 100%` it works, but that might not work for you when the window height is smaller.

So, if you want to use `min-height` to set the height, then it can't be on a table.

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of `display:table` in the container and `display:table-cell` in `.content` and `.nav`. I replaced it with `display:inline-block` in `.content` and `.nav`. I then used `position:absolute` for `.nav`, and set a `padding-left:215px` for the `.content`. This gave a sidebar that took up the whole height, but I'm not sure if its a work around you want to do. Up to you. Good luck!